# How can I isolate parts of a page so that ids are not looked up in different svgs?

Tags: html, svg

Here the use element in the other svg refers to an elements in the first svg.

```
<!-- isolate me -->
<svg>
  <rect id ="a" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10"/>
  <use href="#a" fill="red" x="0" y="0" />
</svg>

<!-- isolate me -->
<svg>
  <use href="#a" fill="blue" x="0" y="0" />
</svg>
```

Is it possible to isolate parts of a page so that ids are not looked up in different parts of the page?

Further requirements:

- As few obstructions as possible to manipulating it all with JavaScript

Comment: you could put them in shadow DOM.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. That definitely seems like a good approach.